# Does EF Core allow a filtered/partial unique index which does not allow multiple NULLs?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ef-code-first, entity-framework-core

[EF Core allows](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41439753/7059613) a unique (filtered) index to contain multiple NULLs.

Can I configure it to *not allow* multiple NULLs?

Suppose I've defined a unique index over properties `Column1`, `Column2`, `Column3`:

```
config.Entity<Product>()
    .HasIndex("Column1", "Column2", "Column3")
    .IsUnique();
```

An example:

```
Id   Column1   Column2   Column3
1    100       "foo"     "bar"    // unique
2    100       "foo"     "bar"    // not allowed (dupe)
3    100       NULL      "bar"    // allowed
4    100       NULL      "bar"    // allowed - but I want this to fail
5    100       NULL      "bar"    // allowed - but I want this to fail
6    100       NULL      "bar"    // allowed - but I want this to fail
```

This is what I want:

- Row1 unique
- Row2 fails (unique constraint violation) as it's a dupe of row1
- Row3 allowed because it's different to row1
- Row4/5/6 must fail, because they are dupes of row3

But row4/5/6 do not fail.

Comment: You can change the unique index to not be filtered in your migration code (using for example the .Sql() method

Comment: @ErikEJ the migration generates: `CREATE UNIQUE INDEX [IX_Column1_Column2_Column3] ON [Product] ([Column1Id] ASC,[Column2Id] ASC,[Column3Id] ASC);` how do I change that to not filtered?

Comment: Is that the Index you have in your DB? Can you script that?

Comment: @ErikEJ Yes that's what EF Core generated for me. I think I've come up with a solution, I've added it below...

Comment: Aaah, you never mentioned SQLite!!! Completely different db engine :-(

Comment: @ErikEJ Sorry Erik I didn't know it was relevant - I'm not a super expert like you! :-) What do you think of my solution, does it make sense?

Comment: Sorry I forgot to ask, and assumed SQL Server!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm using SQLite, [which excludes NULLs](https://www.sqlite.org/nulls.html) from the index.

The migration generates this:

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX [IX_Product] ON [Product] 
([Column1Id] ASC, [Column2Id] ASC, [Column3Id] ASC);
```

So in the migration class, I removed that, and replaced it with a `Sql("...")` call with:

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX [IX_Product] ON [Product] 
(COALESCE([Column1Id],"") ASC, COALESCE([Column2Id],"") ASC, COALESCE([Column3Id],"") ASC);
```

And now it enforces uniqueness of NULLs.

(I've tested this on SQLite, not sure about SQL Server.)

Answer (score 0):

In EF Core the fluent `.HasFilter(string)` is what you're looking for.

You will still need this index to compare in the case that column2 has a value

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Model>()
    .HasIndex("column1", "column2", "column3")
    .IsUnique();
```

But when column2 is null, the above index will not fail an insert/update based on matching column1 and column3, so we need this additional unique index to handle that case explicitly.

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Model>()
    .HasIndex("column1", "column3")
    .HasFilter("column2 IS NULL")
    .IsUnique();
```

Now, when column2 is null, it will use this OTHER index instead and will correctly fail the duplicate entries as you expect.

**BOTH** indexes are required!!

[Here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/indexes?tabs=data-annotations#index-filter) you can learn more.