# EF Core Unique constraints with "NULL" values

Tags: entity-framework, npgsql

The solution of [Does EF Core allow a unique column to contain multiple nulls?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41439434/does-ef-core-allow-a-unique-column-to-contain-multiple-nulls/63667834#63667834) works perfect with
Microsoft SQL Server but not with PostgreSQL. Is there a solution which works also with PostgreSQL (Npgsql provider) ?

Comment: Cross-posted as https://github.com/npgsql/efcore.pg/issues/1483

Answer (score 2):

You can simply use [a filtered index](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/indexes#index-filter) to specify the WHERE clauses as you wish:

```cs
modelBuilder.Entity<Blog>().HasIndex(b => b.SomeInt)
    .HasFilter(@"""SomeInt"" IS NOT NULL")
    .IsUnique();
```

This creates the index as follows:

```sql
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX "IX_Blogs_SomeInt" ON "Blogs" ("SomeInt") WHERE "SomeInt" IS NOT NULL;
```

Comment: +1 - Filtered indexes were the way to do this in PostGres 14
Note there is a new [NULLS NOT DISTINCT](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8289253/) alternative in 15+